# Paypal REST API: How to set no shipping for recurring digital subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using the PayPal REST API, and although you can assign a web profile experience for an individual one-off payment, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this for a subscription plan or agreement.  Since I'm setting up an agreement for a purely digital product the shipping field is redundant and has actually led to lost sales due to the "shipping" country sometimes disagreeing with the billing country.

Is this possible or is it yet another feature overlooked by this API?

Comment: Depends on the type of account you are having and if the sales volume changes during the subscription: [as seen in the docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/recurring-payments/)

Comment: @martinweise I'm using the REST API, not the classic API.